How to deserialize Raw Xml having variable number of properties using MassTransit RabbitMQ
I used the following configuration code for consuming raw message in MassTransit. I am also using MassTransit.Newtonsoft library
For Raw XML
configuration.UseRawXmlDeserializer()
For XML, the root element will be the same but the children properties will vary.
Example
<sample><name>TEst</name></sample>
<sample><a>1</a><b>2</b></sample>
But what should we define in the type(record, class) to be used in IConsumer ?
How should we define the Model Class for the consumer (IConsumer) to deserialize the message?
For XML We tried defining model like :-
[XmlRoot("sample")]
public class SampleMessage {
 [XmlAnyElement]
 public XmlElement xmlElements[] { get; set; }

} 

But it is not able to give value for the elements defined inside the  node

string?      then you'll have to "cast it" (or rather parse it) .. as Json or Xml .. ?

@granadaCoder Both are separate consumers.  I am trying to look for any example in Masstransit where we can deserialise generic xml

@granadaCoder Can you help us here?

Your question is ambiguous in one area.  Are you using the SAME (queue or subscription) to pass BOTH types of messages?     or are they different queues/subscriptions?     My "use a string" was geared toward using the SAME .. which it is usually a bad idea to put 2 different kinds of message-types/contracts into the same pipeline IMHO.

@granadaCoder  Reframed the question to make it clear.   I am trying to figure out how to consume generic xml with same root element from a single queue in the consumer.   It works if there is a fixed schema for the message but in my case the schema is changing with same root element

I am guessing.  But MassTransit (and many other things) that have built in Deserialization .. are doing the "common thing" of (STRICT) mapping to a POCO.  You cannot map to a strongly-typed POCO because your values are "fluid".           You will probably have to write a custom deserializer.  Quick internet search found this : https://gist.github.com/MikeGoldsmith/2e07b64cf25ffd259ec6     I would try to find a "looser" domain model.  IDictionary<string, string> is a typical.  Collection < KeyValuePair < string, string> is another.     to at least get away from the Xml or Json loose objects.

@granadaCoder  How do I write a xml custom deserializer? I am thinking to convert the incoming xml to a string and pass it through to the consumer

I don't know. Follow the link I gave you.  Hint : "  public class InterfaceConverter : JsonConverter"      that's a custom json-converter.  maybe there is one for xml.  I gave a breadcrumb.
